Desugaring for an APK with minSdk=23 (Android 6)
I’m trying to understand desugar_jdk_libs and the impact on a minSdk=23 APK.
Having recently added the kotlinx datetime API, I noticed the app was crashing on older versions of Android due to the lack of java.time.Instant. So I'm enabling desugaring.
One key area of confusion, is how the gradle properties sourceCompatibility, targetCompatibility and kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = ... } impact the results.
From what I can gather, these should all be set to the same thing.
Similarly, which version of desugar_jdk_libs to use because 1.1.* is supposedly for JDK 7, whereas 1.2.* is for JDK 11. How do these JDK levels correspond to the ones mentioned above?
I've briefly tested my app using JDK 8, 11 and 17, and they all seem to work.
Which JDK version should I use, and why?

Which JDK version should I use? It depends which version of desugar_jdk_libs you want to use like for JDK 8 APIs, set sourceCompatibility, targetCompatibility, and kotlinOptions.jvmTarget to 1.8, and use desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.x.
For JDK 11+ APIs, set them to 11, and use desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.x.

At the moment I'm using JDK 17, because that seems to be the default value for kotlinOptions jvmTarget, and I don't have any preference otherwise. Is there a downside to using JDK 17?

Using JDK 17 is fine as long as you don’t run into desugaring limitations, but it may add complexity if you're not using JDK 17-specific features. If simplicity and compatibility are more important, JDK 8 or 11 might be safer choices, especially for older devices.

To be honest I'm not sure if I might inadvertently be using JDK >8 features. And what about dependencies, could they be influencing matters?
